# How can i round the amount field to 2 decimals while inserting to Mysql table

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, .net-2.0

How can to round the value to 2 decimals before it is inserting it to `mysql` database. Suppose if i have my amount field as `800` while inserting to database i would like to round it to `800.00` and also if i enter `234.56` i would like to insert this as it is, if `345.5655` means i would like to insert as `345.56`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to formate string like this

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.##}", value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you store the value in a `DECIMAL` column.

```
Decimal value = 345.5655M;
Decimal roundedValue = Math.Round(value, 2);
```

Then insert the `roundedValue` into the database.

If you want to control the rounding you can use an overload where you specify a [`MidpointRounding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) value.

If you don't round the value before inserting it into the database (assuming that the precision on the database is 2) you run the risk of truncating (instead of rounding) the value:

> When such a [DECIMAL] column is assigned a value with more digits following the decimal point than are permitted by the specified scale, the value is converted to that scale. (The precise behavior is operating system-specific, but generally the effect is truncation to the permissible number of digits.)

A `Decimal` stores the precision that was used when it was created meaning that `3.9M.ToString()` returns `3.9` while `3.90M.ToString()` returns `3.90` (even though the numbers are equal). However, using `Math.Round` will truncate any trailing zero decimals. If you want to round `3.9M` to `3.90M` you need to parse the number from a string:

```
var roundedValue = Decimal.Parse(
   value.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
);
```

However, I don't know if the trailing zero decimals will be retained by MySQL.

Comment: But if i have my value as `3.90 ` if i use ur code i am getting as `3.9` what should i do

Answer (score 1):

If you are using parameterized/prepared statements and the MySQL [Connector/NET](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) provider, you would just use the normal rounding functions (`Math.Round()`) and use the result of that as the value of the parameter executing the query:

```
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) 
{
  command.Text = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (@v1, @v2)";
  var parameter1 = command.CreateParameter();
  parameter1.Name = "@v1";
  parameter1.Value = Math.Round(myValue, 2);
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
  // ... 
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```